# I am trying to apply Lambda Function on a Single Pandas dataframe Column to encode data and combine several values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, encoding

I have some data on which I am doing feature engineering. I am trying to encode the categorical features but am not doing it successfully.  It is only giving me one value, vs 2.  I can't see what is wrong with my code and have tried many different ways in Pandas.

I am trying to take the feature LotShape and turn it into 2 values by combining 'IR1', 'IR2', and 'IR3' into a single value, 2, and 'Reg' as 1. However, everything is returning as 2. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
def irreg(df):
if 'IR1' or 'IR2' or 'IR3' in df['LotShape']:
return 2
else:
return 1

df['LotShape_encoded']=list(map(lambda x: irreg(df['LotShape']),df['LotShape']))
df.LotShape_encoded.value_counts()

2 1460
Name: LotShape_encoded, dtype: int64
```

The original value_counts is this:

```
Reg 925
IR1 484
IR2 41
IR3 10
Name: LotShape, dtype: int64
```

I've even tried this for the function, but it doesn't like it:

```
def irreg(df):
    for i in df['LotShape']:
        if df['LotShape'] =='IR1' or df['LotShape'] =='IR2' or df['LotShape'] =='IR3':
            i=2
        else:
            i=1
    return df['LotShape']

df['LotShape_encoded'] = df.assign(lambda x: irreg(df['LotShape']))
```

It gives me

> TypeError: DataFrame.assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I'm at a loss right now.  I don't know what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `numpy.where` (or `numpy.select` if you have more than 2 values):

```
df['LotShape_encoded'] = np.where(df['LotShape'].isin(['IR1', 'IR2', 'IR3']), 2, 1)
```

Don't use `lambda` function if you don't need it. Here you have a function that takes a `Series` as argument (and not a `DataFrame` as your variable name suggests). In your function, you return 2 if your `Series` contain 'IRE1' or 'IRE2' or 'IRE3'. Except if you have only 'Reg' values, the function will always return 2:

```
def irreg(sr):  # Series not a DataFrame
    mask = sr.isin(['IR1', 'IR2', 'IR3'])
    return np.where(mask, 2, 1)

df['LotShape_encoded'] = irreg(df['LotShape'])
```

Other point: use `assign` only if you want to create a new column dynamically AND chain to another pandas method else don't use it.

**Update**

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'LotShape': ['IR1', 'IR2', 'IR3', 'Reg']})
df['LotShape_encoded'] = np.where(df['LotShape'].isin(['IR1', 'IR2', 'IR3'], 2, 1)
print(df)

# Output
  LotShape  LotShape_encoded
0      IR1                 2
1      IR2                 2
2      IR3                 2
3      Reg                 1
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I use lambda if I don't need it?  I guess I need to learn more about it and how to properly use it, and how it is intended.

I do like your explanation.  I was thinking, and tried and failed, that there should be a way to dynamically go through the unique values to encode them in this manner.  Would I be able to do it with your method?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. I sent you a message on chat about lambda function

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. Thanks.

```
def irreg(df):
    if df['LotShape'] =='IR1' or df['LotShape'] =='IR2' or df['LotShape'] =='IR3':
        return 2
    else:
        return 1
    
df['LotShape_encoded'] = df.apply(lambda df:irreg(df), axis=1)
df.LotShape_encoded.value_counts()
```

Comment: It works but it's really sub optimized. You call your function X times (X = len(df)). Use vectorized method